# c++ duplicate class definition in different source file

Tags: c++, c++17

This is the minimum reproducible code, the code no namespace and header file，The test can compile and run normally, but the results obtained do not match expectations.

- test-a.cc

```
class TestStamp
{
public:
    TestStamp(){}
    inline static std::string Name = "foo-stamp-1";
    std::string GetStampName() const { return TestStamp::Name; }
};

TEST(TestFoo, Example) {
  auto stamp = std::make_shared<TestStamp>();
  std::cout << stamp->GetStampName();
}
```

- test-b.cc

```
class TestStamp
{
public:
    TestStamp(){}
    inline static std::string Name = "foo-stamp-2";
    std::string GetStampName() const { return TestStamp::Name; }
};

TEST(TestBar, Example) {
  auto stamp = std::make_shared<TestStamp>();
  std::cout << stamp->GetStampName();
}
```

I found that both the test of `a.cc` and the test of `b.cc` use `TestStamp` of `a.cc`. In the other words, that means the output of both tests are `foo-stamp-1`

These `TestStamp` are fixture objects, I expect them to take effect only in their own test files.

I don’t know if this is correct. If it’s incorrect, why doesn’t it cause a compilation error?

Comment: If you do not link them together ,there would be no error

Comment: Many things in C++ are Undefined Behaviour, and the C++ standard often says "no diagnostic required". Crank up your warnings level and consider also using static analysis tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don’t know if this is correct.

One Definition Rule states that all definitions of a class and inline variable must be identical across all translation units. Your definitions differ, which violates the language rule. Therefore the program is ill-formed.

> why doesn’t it cause a compilation error?

Language implementation is not required to diagnose One Definition Rule violations. In practice, the compiler cannot diagnose it because it compiles programs one translation unit at a time.

> I expect them to take effect only in their own test files.

To achieve this, define the classes in the anonymous namespace:

```
namespace {

class TestStamp { ... };

}
```

This gives the class a unique name in each translation unit. This way each class is separate and can be defined differently.

Answer (score 1):

> In any translation unit, a template, type, function, or object can have no more than one definition. Some of these can have any number of declarations. A definition provides an instance.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule